# Ionic/AngularJS - state.go without controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I use Ionic for builing apps. I have one problem that I don't know how to solve. I want to redirect user to another tab. I read about state.go() but these probably won't work here. It's not in controller. User needs to be redirect to another tab after he receive notification and clicks "Show". This is my code. Can you help me?

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

      FCMPlugin.getToken(
        function(token){
          console.log("Użytkownik zarejestrowany");
        },
        function(err){
          console.log('Nie udało się połączyć z usługą powiadamiania');
        }
      )

      FCMPlugin.onNotification(
        function(data){
          if (data.wasTapped){
            // I need that code here
          } else {

            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
               title: "Notification",
               template: 'Want to read?',
               cancelText: 'I want to read',
               okText: 'Nope'
             });
            
             confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
               if (res) {
                 // I need that code here
               }
             });

          }
        },
        function(msg){
          console.log("Ok");
        },
        function(err){
          console.log("Error");
        }
      );

  });
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'new tab' in your question.? is it a new page?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarified that. It is exsiting tab:
`.state('zglos', {
    url: '/zglos',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-zglos.html',
    controller: 'ZglosCtrl'
  });`

Comment: you can use `$state.go('zglos')` even in `run block`

Comment: just add dependency and use it, `.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$state` of `ui-router` even in `run block`.

Just add the dependency `$state` as the dependency of `run block`.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $state) {

    // code goes here

    $state.go('zglos')
}
```

Comment: I'm so dumb... I tried something but with $stateProvider. Don't know why. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: And if I want to send parameters like this:
`$state.go('zglos', { "newsId" : myId } );`
Is it correct? Doesn't work for me.
`.state('zglos', {
      url: '/zglos/:newsId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-zglos.html',
      controller: 'ZglosCtrl'
    })`

Comment: check if you have `myId` or not.

Comment: If I show `ajdi` in alert, it gives me "4" with quotation marks. Shouldn't it show just `4` ? Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: you can use `parseInt(ajdi)` to convert string to number.

Comment: I did. That was not a problem in this case. Still doesn't work. When I run my project in web it works but on device or emulator it doesn't.

Comment: what issue you are getting?

Comment: I go to redirected tab but with nothing inside. This tab have controller that gets content from my database. In this case should show me text and image but it is just blank tab.

Comment: I'm trying but I don't know yet how to check console in android emulator

Comment: Console doesnt show nothing. It shows me correct `ajdi` but still redirects to blank page. Ok I know. In 'zglos' tab value of `ajdi` is NaN

Comment: in your controller check `$stateParams`

Comment: Yes. It works in web perfectly. But not in device emulator.

Comment: I know what the problem was. It was these quotation marks. I just do javascript replace() function and it works. But parseInt doesnt work in this case.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for help!

Comment: great, pls vote it bro, if you dont mind. have a good day. :)

Comment: I did but I don't have 15 reputation points so you probably dont se it ;) Have a nice day